# MVC Upload ProgressBar

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, progress-bar

I have read many links in this forum and the asp.net forum and searched Google. I have found loads of progress upload bars, but not one that suits my specific needs. So i was hoping someone could help. I need an upload progress bar that does not use, flash, php, html 5 or any codebehindfiles, was hoping to find a javascript pure upload progress bar. Has anyone used anything like this before?

Thanks

Marcel.

Comment: I need something which would actually perform the upload as well as monitor the upload progress. Sorry i didn't make that very clear.

Comment: you can edit the question instead of adding information in a comment. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if that's possible with all the stipulations you've added. The upload is a purely server side process. You can use javascript to poll the progress using ajax, but that still requires a server side code file.

The file uploader I always use is http://slfileupload.codeplex.com/

This allows you to do multiple files, have progress bars, and hook into events with javascript. It is silverlight, so that might rule it out for you.

The only other thing I can think of, with the limits you've imposed, is showing a 'working' gif, like a spinner or something. It's not true progress, but it'll show the user that something is happening.

Answer (score 1):

[Valums Uploader](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/). It uses pure Javascript (uploads file using Iframe)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one that doesn't use anything except Javascript/HTML/CSS

http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload

Comment: Didn't see his flash comment, sorry. Updated :)